# Complete list of GetTypeCode codes?

Tags: c#

Where can I get a complete list of Type.GetTypeCode codes? I'm working on a switch statement and it would be nice to know what the *complete list of* numbers correspond to.

Comment: You guys are so brutal. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an Enum, so you can just look them up in MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode.aspx

Since C# also supports Reflection, you can do something like this:

```
foreach (var typeCode in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TypeCode)))
{
   Console.WriteLine(typeCode);  // you might need .ToString() or cast to int, I'm too lazy to compile
}
```